# difference between working on R directly working under install.packages("sparklyr")

Tags: r

I was just reading the article https://spark.rstudio.com/
But I am not sure what is the difference between working on R directly working under `install.packages("sparklyr")` packages

Could you let me know, I am confused

Comment: have a look here; https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apache_Spark ```sparklyr``` helps you to work with Spark using R with the (common) ```dplyr``` syntax

Answer (score 0):

The `sparklyr` package gives you a very similar env to what `tidy` and `dplyr` provides you in R. But you directly work with spark then you will have to use the spark context to run your commands. Below is the documentation:

https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sparkr.html

Comment: thanks, Doubt here. The link is telling "SparkR provides a distributed data frame implementation that supports operations like selection, filtering, aggregation etc" But these operations are there even without installing spark in R right?

Comment: Yes, these operations are still present in base R. The major difference comes when you try work on `spark` specific RDD or on other objects, then you will have to use spark specific `functions` . I suggest you to go with `spark` specific functions to work on RDD as these have much greater support and better documentation. Or else if you have the option of using `pyspark` or `scala` use these for spark.

Comment: Cool. I am reading few articles. What I understand is we should first load excel data in Spark cluster and then we need to connect spark in R, Am I right? I am not from programming background and little difficult to understand

Comment: It depends, if you already have the `spark context`, set in your env, or have spark cluster say at `hdInsights`, then you just need to run `R` commands on your data frame or RDD.